# cloudera hadoop mapreduce job GC overhead limit exceeded error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, heap-memory, cloudera

I am running a canopy cluster job (using mahout) on a cloudera cdh4. the content to be clustered has about 1m records (each record is less than 1k in size). the whole hadoop environment (including all the nodes) is running in a vm with 4G memory. the installation of cdh4 is by default. I got the following exception when running the job.

It looks the job client should need a higher jvm heap size according to the exception. However, there are quite a few configuration options for jvm heap size in cloudera manager. I changed "Client Java Heap Size in Bytes" from 256MiB to 512MiB. However, it didnt improve.

Any hints/tips on setting these heap size options?

```
13/07/03 17:12:45 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/07/03 17:12:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201307031710_0001
13/07/03 17:12:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:13:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:13:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 2% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:14:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 3% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:14:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 4% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:15:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 5% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:17:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 6% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:18:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 7% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:20:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:22:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:25:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:28:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:31:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:35:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:40:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:46:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/03 17:55:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/03 18:08:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/07/03 18:59:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/03 18:59:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
13/07/03 18:59:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:00:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:01:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:04:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:07:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:12:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:19:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:29:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/03 19:43:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:49:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:49:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
13/07/03 20:49:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:50:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:52:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:54:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/03 20:58:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:03:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:10:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:19:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:31:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:31:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 65.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)

13/07/03 21:32:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:33:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:35:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:38:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:42:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:48:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/03 21:56:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/03 22:07:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/03 22:26:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:35:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:35:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
13/07/03 23:35:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:36:16 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:38:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:40:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:44:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:50:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/03 23:58:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:10:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:21:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 7% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:21:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:250)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 65.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:237)

13/07/04 00:21:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:22:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:23:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:26:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:28:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:32:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:37:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:44:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/04 00:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:16:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:32:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:32:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201307031710_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: GC overhead limit exceeded
13/07/04 01:32:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:33:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 10% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:35:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:38:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 12% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:43:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 13% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:49:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 14% reduce 0%
13/07/04 01:59:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 15% reduce 0%
13/07/04 02:12:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 16% reduce 0%
13/07/04 02:37:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 17% reduce 0%
13/07/04 03:31:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 8% reduce 0%
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201307031710_0001
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=8
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=8
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=11443502
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/07/04 03:32:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException: Canopy Job failed processing vector
```

Comment: Does your application need to use much memory? If not, maybe there is some bug in your application eating the whole memory.

Comment: it is running the mahout canopy cluster, so should not be the application bug. i can see each child client was allocated around 200MB which may not be enough in my case.

Comment: @zsxwing you should write this as "-Xmx1024M" for exactly this reason: you put one too many zeroes there. That's 10.24G

Answer (score 3):

The Mahout jobs are very memory intensive. I don't know whether the mappers or reducers are the culprits, but, either way you will have to tell Hadoop to give them more RAM. "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" is just a way of saying "out of memory" -- means the JVM gave up trying to reclaim the last 0.01% of available RAM.

How you set this is indeed a little complex, because there are several properties and they changed in Hadoop 2. CDH4 can support Hadoop 1 or 2 -- which one are you using?

If I had to guess: set `mapreduce.child.java.opts` to `-Xmx1g`. But the right answer really depends on your version and your data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your memory settings for Hadoop, as the memory allocated for Hadoop is not enough to accommodate the job requirement you are running, Try to increase the heap memory and verify, due to over uses of memory OS might be killing the processes due to which job is failing.